# Websocket doesn't work with https and apache 2.4 as web server

Tags: apache, ssl, https, socket.io, httpd.conf

I'm using [apache2.4](/questions/tagged/apache2.4) web server (with django web framework) and [socketio](/questions/tagged/socketio) python library for socket connections.

Following is the relevant configuration in Apache's [httpd.conf](/questions/tagged/httpd.conf) file:

```
Listen 8088

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

The Apache server is listening on the 8088 port number. Following are the relevant contents of [httpd-ssl.conf](/questions/tagged/httpd-ssl.conf) file:

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost _default_:8080>

SSLProxyEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:8091/$1 [P,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

The HTTPS is configured with port 8080 and the backend socketio server is listening to port 8091.
The rewrite rule written above should 'forward' the WebSocket upgrade requests to the socketio server and establish the socket connection.
However, whenever a client tries to connect to this server, it raises `socketio.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection error`
Following is the client code for connection establishment:

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()
sio.connect("https://<server_ip>:8080/", transports=["websocket"])
```

Is there any modification required in the apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ProxyWebsocketFallbackToProxyHttp off`.
See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_proxy.html#protoupgrade .